# Convert Python dictionary which has list as values into simple dictionnary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has a list as value like following:

```
dict = {"a":["b","c","d"]}
```

And I want to have this form :

```
dict = {"a":"b","a":"c","a":"d"}
```

Comment: `dict` keys are unique. Perhaps you were looking for a `list` of `tuples` for example `[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'),..]` ? If you would tell us more, maybe we can propose a better data structure for your usecase

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? Even if you could have duplicate keys, what would you expect to be returned when you use ```dict['a']```?

Comment: Thank you for responses. Actually, I'm trying to store the dictionary dict = {"a":["b","c","d"]} in a CSV file with this format :
a,b
a,c
a,d

Comment: @azrara: that is the reason why you should always give some context with the question. Building a flattened dictionary is not possible (because keys are unique), but is not  required to write the content into a CSV file. If you edit your question to say that what you want is in fact a csv file, you could have answers.

Comment: @SergeBallesta ok thank you. I'll give more context in another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comments, you want to write the dict content to a csv file. There is no need for flattening anything:

```
d = {"a":["b","c","d"]}    # never use dict or list as a variable name to not hide builtins
with open("file.csv", "w", newline="") as fd:
    wr = csv.writer(fd)
    for k,v in d.items():
        for x in v:
            wr.writerow((k,x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since dictionaries have unique keys you can't create directories. I think the list of tuples would be a better idea. Here's a sample on how it can be achieved.

```
dict = {"a":["b","c","d"]}

newList = list()

for key, value in dict.items():
    for i in value:
        newList.append((key, i))

print(newList)
```

Output for this as follows.

```
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd')]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using a comprehension is more *pythonic* (and more efficient) that repeatedly adding to a list: `newlist = [(key, i) for key, value in dict.items() for i in value]`. Probably less readable for a Python beginner, but really more pythonic.